# Twitter file size limit for audio & video

Tags: twitter

We can upload audio & video directly to Twitter.

Can someone help me know what the file size limitation is for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File size must not exceed 512 mb.**

From the [Twitter Developer Page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices):

> **Video specifications and recommendations**
>
> **Recommended:**
>
> - Recommended Video Codec: H264 High Profile
> - Recommended Frame Rates: 30 FPS, 60 FPS
> - Recommended Video Resolution: 1280x720 (landscape), 720x1280 (portrait), 720x720 (square)
> - Recommended Minimum Video Bitrate: 5,000 kbps
> - Recommended Minimum Audio Bitrate: 128 kbps
> - Recommended Audio Codec: AAC LC
> - Recommended Aspect Ratio: 16:9 (landscape or portrait), 1:1 (square)
>
> **Advanced:**
>
> - Frame rate must be 60 FPS or less
> - Dimensions must be between 32x32 and 1280x1024
> - File size must not exceed 512 mb
> - Duration must be between 0.5 seconds and 140 seconds
> - Aspect ratio must be between 1:3 and 3:1
> - Must have 1:1 pixel aspect ratio
> - Only YUV 4:2:0 pixel format is supported
> - Audio must be AAC with Low Complexity profile. High-Efficiency AAC is not supported
> - Audio must be mono or stereo, not 5.1 or greater
> - Must not have open GOP
> - Must use progressive scan